# Getting error when trying to print class definition with inspect.getsource())

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am defining a class:

```
class MyFirstClass:
    pass
```

After, I am trying to print the definition of `MyFirstClass` class:

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(MyFirstClass))
```

But I am getting error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22132/2338486789.py in <module>
      1 import inspect
----> 2 print(inspect.getsource(MyFirstClass))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py in getsource(object)
    971     or code object.  The source code is returned as a single string.  An
    972     OSError is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
--> 973     lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
    974     return ''.join(lines)
    975 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py in getsourcelines(object)
    953     raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
    954     object = unwrap(object)
--> 955     lines, lnum = findsource(object)
    956 
    957     if istraceback(object):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py in findsource(object)
    766     is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
    767 
--> 768     file = getsourcefile(object)
    769     if file:
    770         # Invalidate cache if needed.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py in getsourcefile(object)
    682     Return None if no way can be identified to get the source.
    683     """
--> 684     filename = getfile(object)
    685     all_bytecode_suffixes = importlib.machinery.DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES[:]
    686     all_bytecode_suffixes += importlib.machinery.OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES[:]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py in getfile(object)
    651             if getattr(module, '__file__', None):
    652                 return module.__file__
--> 653         raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))
    654     if ismethod(object):
    655         object = object.__func__

TypeError: <class '__main__.MyFirstClass'> is a built-in class
```

I expected oputput is:

```
class MyFirstClass:
    pass
```

How to correctly use `inspect.getsource())` to get my expected output (definition of `MyFirstClass` class)?

Comment: if this is just within an interpreter, there's no file to refer to

Comment: @ti7 In the same Jupyter notebooke this code works well: `import inspect
  
def fun(a,b):
    # product of 
    # two numbers
    return a*b
  
# use getsource()
print(inspect.getsource(fun))` But code in question gives error. So I do not think that the problem is in Jupyter.

Comment: @ti7 I am running this in Jupyter. What you mean by "file"? Do you mean source file? As I understand `inspect.getsource()` is getting the information from environment and not from source file. Am I right?

Comment: Source code is simply not kept in the Python environment.  The file that the source code was originally loaded from is the only possible place that `getsource()` could retrieve it from, therefore it can only work in cases where the source code *was* loaded from a file.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you. I thought the information was obtained from memory of the script. Is there any way that uses memory to get that information?

Comment: No, because Python has absolutely no need for the script itself once it has been compiled to bytecode.

Comment: Does this code work for you for a class loaded from a file?